# Wordpress Contact 7 Datepicker calculate league age

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datepicker, contact-form-7

I created an online registration form for my Little League website using Contact Form 7. I have installed the Datepicker plugin which works fine. What I am trying to do is display the League age based on the DOB (entered with Datepicker) - "2014-04-30"

I have it working with this outside of Contact Form 7:

```
$('#dob').datepicker({
onSelect: function(value, ui) {
    var today = new Date(), 
        dob = new Date(value), 
        Lage = new Date("2014-04-30"),
        age = new Date(Lage - dob).getFullYear() - 1970;

    $('#age').text(age);
},
maxDate: '+0d',
yearRange: '1920:2010',
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true
```

});

But I would like to use Contact Form 7 and have the result display in a text box i.e.

```
[text LL_Age id:L_age]
```

EDIT: Alternatively, I wouldn't care if I could achieve the same thing without Datepicker.

"#DOB - Lage = L_age"

Thanks for any help.

Comment: place the form on a page and get the ids of the field to populate, then you can modify the jQuery to suit.

Comment: The form is on a page and I set the ids. The formula I specified above are the ids. I need figure out how to get L_age into a textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact form 7 uses form inputs. You need to use the jQuery .val() method to set this. I can't see the rest of your code but if its not in a document ready function, make sure the jquery is inserted below the form.

```
jQuery('#dob').datepicker({
     maxDate: '+0d',
     yearRange: '1920:2010',
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     onSelect: function(value, ui) {
       var today = new Date(), 
       dob = new Date(value), 
       Lage = new Date("2014-04-30"),
       age = new Date(Lage - dob).getFullYear() - 1970;

       jQuery('#age').val(age);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. jQuery('#age').val(age); is what I needed.